# Laravel mail function - scope issue?

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I'm using laravel's Mail function to send my user's confirmation email. The problem is, I'm getting an error "Undefined variable: email"

This is my code:

```
    $email="someemail@gmail.com";
    $name="thename";

    \Mail::send('emails.verify', ['confirmation_code' => $user->confirmation_code], function($message) {
        $message->from('myemail@myserver.com', 'Confirmation')->to($email, $name)->subject('Please verify your email address');
    });
```

Apparently the declared variables $email and $name are not on the same scope as $message->from.. is being called..

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `use` statement in your closure to "include" the `$email` and `$name` variable:

```
\Mail::send('emails.verify', 
    ['confirmation_code' => $user->confirmation_code], 
    function($message) use ($email, $name) {
        $message->from('myemail@myserver.com', 'Confirmation')
                ->to($email, $name)
                ->subject('Please verify your email address');
    }
);
```

Comment: you're missing `$name` in the use statement

Answer (score 0):

you need to use those variable

```
$email="someemail@gmail.com";
$name="thename";

\Mail::send('emails.verify', ['confirmation_code' => $user->confirmation_code], function($message) use ($email,$name) {
    $message->from('myemail@myserver.com', 'Confirmation')->to($email, $name)->subject('Please verify your email address');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to use an undefined variable 'email' within a function, so you need to include a 'use' statement to make 'email' variable available within the closure, like so:

```
  $email="someemail@gmail.com";
  $name="thename";
```

`\Mail::send('emails.verify', ['confirmation_code' => $user->confirmation_code], function($message) use ($email){
    $message->from('myemail@myserver.com', 'Confirmation')->to($email, $name)->subject('Please verify your email address');
});`